# C++: Multiple Sounds without Additional Headers or Libraries

Tags: c++, audio

This is my first post here. I am trying to write a program that plays background music, while still allowing for playing sound effects (i.e. music with gunshots). I wish to play multiple sounds at once WITHOUT using any other libraries or header files. I don't want to use anything besides what comes with Windows XP and my compiler. I don't want links to other libraries, I need example code showing how to do this using vanilla Windows. I am using Windows.h. I have done research into this, and have yet to find an answer that meets my needs. I have heard that multiple threads might be an answer, but cannot get them to work. I am relatively new to coding.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to interface with your audio hardware directly? Well that's going to tough. You realise that would then only work with hardware that has the same interface as yours? This is why people make drivers and sound servers and audio libraries.

Comment: Why don't you want to use DirectSound? It would provide exactly the functionality you desire.

Comment: maybe you should at least take a look at DirectX/DirectSound...

Comment: You say you have done research, but do not say what you have tried which has failed. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Do you demand some coffee too with the fully working code? cookies? a stripper?

Comment: I have tried using multiple threads to play multiple threads at once, but I can't get it to compile properly with any of the methods I have found. In addition, all of the things I found that I could get to compile either played the sounds in order, or didn't play the sounds at all, despite me trying everything I could think of.

Comment: @OneForOne And I am not asking for completely functioning programs, just snipits that actually work instead of theories that have no explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you've said you want to keep it simple, but it sounds like you want to use DirectSound. It provides one primary buffer (good for your background music) and a series of secondary buffers (good for your sound effects). Its very easy to work with, and doesn't require much more than linking dsound.lib

Also, completely unhelpful: You should be sure to upgrade to Windows 7 or 8 before April. Microsoft will no longer support it and you'll be a great risk for exploitation.

Comment: Thank you for the complete and helpful answer. I will try using the multiple buffers in directsound like you said.